# how i can use two form in one page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 <div id="formContainer">
    <form id="login" runat="server">
        <a href="#" id="flipToRecover" class="flipLink">Forgot?</a>
        <asp:TextBox ID="loginEmail" Text="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="loginPass" TextMode="Password" runat="server" value="pass"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"  />
    </form>
    <form id="recover" method="post" action="./">
        <a href="#" id="flipToLogin" class="flipLink">Forgot?</a>
        <input type="text" name="recoverEmail" id="recoverEmail" value="Email" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover" />
      <%--  <asp:Button ID="btnrecover" runat="server" Text="Recover" OnClick="btnrecover_Click"  />--%>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my code and I need to write a code on recover button.
But error came that is only one form is used.

Can anyone help to solve this error?

I want to write code on both buttons to submit and recover. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need two forms on one page? From the looks of it, you could achieve the same thing with a single form.

Comment: Just like that, I believe.

Comment: no it not possible in one from, with i click on forget passwrod, it flip and show another form and i want to send email on another button.

Comment: I don't work with asp much...but not hard to look at the 2 forms and see big differences in structure of the two form tags

Comment: ok, i remove runat=server, its work but not able to write code on button click.

Comment: Remove `runat="server"` in your form tag

Comment: if i remove runat=server then i am not able to click on button @Ramesh Rajendran

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Panel control` instead of form ,

```
   <div id="formContainer">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pTest" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
            <a href="#" id="flipToRecover" class="flipLink">Forgot?</a>
            <asp:TextBox ID="loginEmail" Text="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="loginPass" TextMode="Password" runat="server" value="pass"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" DefaultButton="btnrecover">
            <a href="#" id="flipToLogin" class="flipLink">Forgot?</a>
            <input type="text" name="recoverEmail" id="recoverEmail" value="Email" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnrecover" runat="server" Text="Recover" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

You can also reference [this link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/aspnet/9aJL070612-Asp.net-Enter-Key-to-submit-form.html)  !

Comment: i use panel instead of form but it show error....... "Control 'loginEmail' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

Comment: i trying like this way also... one form and other recover one is in panel  but its show error...."Control 'btnrecover' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."......

Comment: ok thanks, but i put your code and run my application then i got error again "
Control 'loginEmail' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. "........ :(

Comment: and also i wirte code of login on btnlogin ..... but when i debug it on go on breakpoint.

Comment: Oh , by the way , do you have `<form runat="server">` tag in your master Page or not ?

Comment: i am not using master page i am write in page <form runat="server" >  <div id="formContainer">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pTest" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
            <a href="#" id="flipToRecover" class="flipLink">Forgot?</a>
           textbox..
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" DefaultButton="btnrecover">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Recover" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnrecover" runat="server" Text="Recover" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div></form>

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, you can extend your first form to Control, then you can see it on your Toolbox. Then just drag it to your second Form.

Comment: but not allow runat=server in 2 form :(